# Firebase and reactjs: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to init my Firebase app with reactjs.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

import 'firebase/database';

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.app = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);
    console.log(this.app);
    this.db = this.app.database().ref().child('notes');

    this.state = {
      notes: []
    }
  }
```

And here is the Error:

> Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists
>   (app/duplicate-app).
>
> > 13 |   this.app = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);

Some help please.

Comment: The error and all the internet says this is because somehow you are initializing the Firebase multiple times somehow. In another file, within a loop etc.

Comment: Ty, What can i do?

Comment: You can see your question is duplicate and there are some suggestions. You can check your code if there is any other Firebase initialization by accident.